# Who is the mysterious woman in The Sad Tale of the Brothers Grossbart?

Tags: character-identification

In the [Sad Tale of the Brothers Grossbart](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316049344):

> The brothers deliver the mysterious woman from the coach to Captain Barousse. She was labeled by multiple characters as being of supernatural or demonic origins. Who, or what, is this woman?

Answer (score 2):

Best I can tell from re-reading a couple of chapters, this woman is possessed by a demonic spirit of some kind. While she never actually comes out and showcases any powers or possession, men seem act very strange around her and seem to be driven to violence by her will.